Dynamically type hint a list of heterogenous objects
I am writing a code to simulate genetic mechanisms (the original biologic mechanism, not the programming algorithm).
I have this simplified code:
class Allele(StrEnum):
    dominant: int
    
    def __new__(cls, value: str, dominant: int) -> Self:
        allele = str.__new__(cls, value)
        allele._value_ = value
        allele.dominant = dominant
        return allele

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.value
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__str__()


class Gene(tuple[Allele, Allele]):
    ALLELE: type[Allele] = Allele

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, Allele: type[Allele], **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.ALLELE = Allele
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        for dominance in sorted([allele.dominant for allele in self.ALLELE], reverse=True): 
            group = set(item for item in self if item.dominant == dominance)
            if len(group) != 0: return ''.join(sorted(group))
        
        return ''
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'({self[0]}, {self[1]})'
    
    def __mul__(self, mother: Self) -> Self:
        return type(self)(random.choice(list(self)), random.choice(list(mother)))

    def __add__(self, mother: Self) -> list[Self]:
        return [type(self)(one, other) for one in self for other in mother]


class Genome(list['Gene | Genome']):

    GENOME: list[type['Gene | Genome']] = []
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, genome: list[type['Gene | Genome']], **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.GENOME = genome
    
    def __init__(self, *args, pure: bool = False) -> None:
        super().__init__([])

        for sequence, Gene in enumerate(self.GENOME):
            if sequence < len(args):
                gene = args[sequence]
            else:
                gene = Gene(pure=pure)

            if not isinstance(gene, Gene) and not isinstance(gene, Genome): 
                raise ValueError(f'Given sequence {args} is not compatabile with Genome mapping {', '.join(Gene.__name__ for Gene in self.GENOME)}!')
            
            self.append(gene)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str: 
        if all(issubclass(GENE, Gene) for GENE in self.GENOME):
            return ''.join(str(gene) for gene in self)
        
        return ', '.join(str(gene) for gene in self)
    
    def __mul__(self, mother: Self) -> Self:
        return type(self)(*(gene * mother[sequence] for sequence, gene in enumerate(self))) # type: ignore - Because gene  *mother[sequence] is Gene | Genome x Gene | Genome  
    
    def __add__(self, mother: Self) -> list[Self]:
        return [type(self)(*genome) for genome in list(itertools.product(*[self[sequence] + mother[sequence] for sequence in range(len(self.GENOME))]))] # type: ignore - Because gene  *mother[sequence] is Gene | Genome x Gene | Genome

As you can see a Genome can be a list of Gene or Genome itself. The reason being that some genes control their stuff alone (like a simplified model for eye colour) and some genes work together to control their stuff (for instance your blood type is controlled by two genes: one for ABO, the other for +/-).
So I can now model this like:
class ABOAntigens(Allele):
    A = 'A', 1
    B = 'B', 1
    O = 'O', 0
class ABO(Gene, Allele=ABOAntigens): pass

class RhesusAntigen(Allele):
    Positive = '+', 1
    Negative = '-', 0
class Rhesus(Gene, Allele=RhesusAntigen): pass

class Blood(Genome, genome=[ABO, Rhesus]): pass

class EyeColour(Allele):
    Brown = 'Brown', 2
    Green = 'Green', 1
    Blue = 'Blue', 0
class Eye(Gene, Allele=EyeColour): pass

class Human(Genome, genome=[Eye, Blood]): pass

As you can see, a Human has an Eye colour and a Blood type which itself is the combination of two genes: ABO and Rhesus.
Since I am type hint obsessed (please bear with me for a bit), I struggle with this line of code on the class Genome:
def __mul__(self, mother: Self) -> Self: 
    return type(self)(*(gene * mother[sequence] for sequence, gene in enumerate(self))) 
    # type: ignore - Because gene * mother[sequence] is Gene | Genome x Gene | Genome  

If father and mother are both Genome of the same species (same class, if I speak python), father * mother is the function that produces a child with 50% of their fatherand mother genome. Of course if they belong to the same class, they have the same genome (class variable GENOME that I initialise on __init_subclass__), but how can I type hint python that as I go through the list[Gene | Genome] both lists will follow the same type pattern?
(the goal is for me to remove the # type: ignore remark and have a type checked code at the same time)

Your custom __mul__ and __add__ methods violate LSP. Do you actually need to subclass list and tuple? Wouldn't Sequence/Iterable suffice?

Indeed they do violate LSP. the fact is that both a Gene and a Genome can be __mul__ed (combined to produce an offspring) and __add__ed (generate all possible combinations of reproduction). However gene offspring and genome offspring are not exactly the same process because combining two genes is just randomly selecting one allele from the father and one allele from the mother whereas combining two genomes is combining the genes in sequencing.

You seem to be doing way too much at the type level, and never actually instantiating any of your classes. Why is Gene a subclass of type hints, rather than a simple wrapper around a list of Allele values?

After tinkering with the code for a while, this is about as good as I could get it to work (indirect link; snippet is too long). I'm unsure of its usability as well as my biology knowledge and thus not posting an answer. My conclusion is that, to make this work perfectly, you would need features not (yet) available in Python's type system.

This is screaming "composition over inheritance."

The errors emitted are correct, your interface for both Gene and Genome says __mul__(self, mother: Self) -> Self, but you self-described the interface as both a Gene and a Genome can be __mul__ed (combined to produce an offspring). From your description, __mul__'s signature is not correctly typed. I would start by figuring out what Python type is supposed to be the result of Gene x Genome and Genome x Gene, then either make the signature more permissive (e.g. __mul__(self, mother: Gene | Genome) -> ???) or use @typing.overloads to handle each combination.

So, I found a solution using Protocol.
In truth, both Gene and Genome are combinable entities, meaning: we can combine two of them to generate a third.
So, I created the following Protocol:
class Combinable(Protocol):
    def __new__(cls, *args, pure: bool = False) -> Self: ...
    @classmethod
    def generator(cls, target:str = '') -> Iterator[Self]: ...
    def __mul__(self, mother: Self) -> Self: ... 
    def __add__(self, mother: Self) -> Iterator[Self]: ...
    def parent(self, father: bool = True) -> Iterator[Self]: ...

Now, both Gene and Genome are compatible with this Protocol and Genome can be re-written as:
class Genome(list[Combinable]):
    GENOME: list[Type[Combinable]] = []
    ...

That means that when I write the __mul__ method, I am actually talking about two Combinable entities that belong to the same class.
def __mul__(self, mother: Self) -> Self: 
    return type(self)(*(gene * mother[sequence] for sequence, gene in enumerate(self)))

